# Piecewise linear structure as generators of $C(M)$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact topological manifold and $C(M)$ the commutative unital $C^*$-algebra of complex valued continuous functions on $M$. Suppose that $M$ admits a piecewise linear structure.

In the introduction of Blackadar and Cuntz's [paper](http://jot.theta.ro/jot/archive/1991-026-002/1991-026-002-003.pdf) it is stated that

> a piecewise linear structure on $M$ may be regarded as a suitable choice of generators of $C(M)$.

**Question:** What makes a choice of generators of $C(M)$ "suitable" so that these generators define a PL structure on $M$? In other words, when exactly does a set of generators of $C(M)$ define a PL structure on $M$?

Any references would be appreciated.